# dealing with nested json array swift

Tags: json, swift, multidimensional-array, swift3, nested

I am trying to convert some json data which i receive from a get request into a usable array or something like this

the json data i recieve looks like this

```
{
"elementlist":{

    "Ready Position":{

"Neutral Grip":["1,2,3,4,5"],"
Back Straight (Concave ir Convex?)":["1,2,3,4,5"],"
Body Low & Feet a little more than sholder width apart":["1,2,3,4,5"],"
Weight on Balls of Feet":["1,2,3,4,5"],"
Head Up":["1,2,3,4,5"],"
Sholder Blades Close":["1,2,3,4,5"],"
Eyes Drilled":["1,2,3,4,5"]
},

"Split Step":{"
Ready Position Conforms":["Yes,No"],"
Body Position Low":["1,2,3,4,5"],"
Legs Loaded/Prepared":["1,2,3,4,5"]
}
}
}
```

this is the swift i am using

```
let playerAPIurl = "http://linkcoachuat.herokuapp.com/api/v1/session/element?organisation=5&group=green&sport=tennis"
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: playerAPIurl)!)
request.httpMethod = "GET"



let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("ERROR")
    }
    else{


        do{

            print("hello")

            let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: Any]

          // Convert myJson into array here

           print(myJson)
                           }

        catch
        {
        }

    }}
```

What i would like to be able to do is get an array of the names of the nested arrays so elementarray = ["Ready Position","Split Step"] and then be able to access the arrays by saying myJson[elementarray[0]] or something similar

im a bit of a swift noob so any help is appreciated please try and explain the answers so they are easily understood

thank you for any help

Answer (score 3):

You can try to downcast that json same way you've already made:

```
let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: Any]

//creating the new array of additional elements
let elementArray: [[String: Any]] = []

//making myJson parsing for additional items
if let readyPosition = myJson?["Ready Position"] as? [String: Any] {
     elementArray.append(readyPosition)
}

if let splitStep = myJson?["Split Step"] as? [String: Any] {
     elementArray.append(splitStep)
}
```

make print(elementArray) to be sure that all was parsed correctly.

Honestly, I prefer to use objects (custom classes or structs) to store values and have an ability to make related instances or values, but up to you

Comment: I am getting an error for the first line of code saying "contextual type [[String : Any]] cannot be used with dictionary literal

Comment: I've edited that line. Just remove ":" between brackets